# R: Average value of vector

Tags: r, average

I'm playing around with R and trying to get the average of a column.  Just `mean(V1)` doesn't work.

[image]

Could anybody give me an advice?
Thank you!

Comment: `mean(D$V1)` ... column names are not first class objects. They are part of a data.frame with a name that needs to be used.

Comment: Do you mean `mean(D$V1)`?

Comment: Yes, thanks. So $ is like the dot-operator?

Comment: Perhaps. it is possible to construct list objects with cascaded calls to `$<-` and then obj$V1$subV1 to extract. Review `?Extract` very carefully.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please add this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A: mean(D$V1) ... column names are not first class objects. They are part of a data.frame with a name that needs to be used.

Q: es, thanks. So $ is like the dot-operator? – user1170330 4 mins ago

A: Perhaps (depending on which language is being compared.) it is possible to construct list objects with cascaded calls to $<- and then obj$V1$subV1 to extract. Review ?Extract very carefully.

Answer (score -1):

if you just want `mean(V1)`, you can attach dataframe with `attach(D)`, but probably I don't want to recommend it as later you may have other dataframes with same variable names and a mess with`attach` and `detach` commands. So, `mean(D$V1)` is the best way.

Comment: Having multiple dataframes in the workspace is not the only reason for newbies to avoid attach. If you make a change to an `attach()`-ed object and then detach it, .... THE CHANGE IS LOST. Very unintuitive. Friends don't let friends use `attach`.